# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable with bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

Here is my .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
 <virtualhosts>
  <virtualhost id="113">
   <name>example.com</name>
   <hostname>myexample.com</hostname>
  </virtualhost>
 </virtualhosts>
</xml>
```

Now I want to extract the value of the id attribute of the `virtualHost` tag (in that case`113`) like described [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes). Here is my code:

```
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

file ="temp.xml"
handler = open(file).read()
soup = Soup(handler,features="lxml")

for vHost in soup.find('virtualhost').find_all('name', string='example.com'):
    print(vHost.parent)#display the right level
    temp=vHost.parent.virtualhost['id']
    print(temp)
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *attrs* function

Use contex manager so you don't have to remember about closing files.

```py
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup

file ="temp.xml"
with open(file) as f:
    handler = f.read()
soup = Soup(handler,features="lxml")

all_names = soup.find('virtualhost').find_all('name', string='example.com')

for vHost in all_names:
    print(vHost.parent)#display the right level
    temp=vHost.parent.attrs['id']
    print(temp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have identified the parent just print this.

```
for vHost in soup.find('virtualhost').find_all('name', string='example.com'):
    print(vHost.parent)#display the right level
    temp=vHost.parent['id']
    print(temp)
```